# Codeigniter Ion Auth register() not returning errors

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, registration, ion-auth

I'm using Ion Auth for authentication and am having difficulty returning validation errors.  The `login();` function returns them as expected and when running `register();`, I'm redirected correctly, however no errors are returned.

Form validation:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation', array(), 'register_form');
$this->register_form->set_rules('first_name', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_fname_label'), 'required|xss_clean');
$this->register_form->set_rules('last_name', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_lname_label'), 'required|xss_clean');
$this->register_form->set_rules('email', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_email_label'), 'required|valid_email');
$this->register_form->set_rules('phone', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_phone_label'), 'required|xss_clean');
$this->register_form->set_rules('company', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_company_label'), 'required|xss_clean');
$this->register_form->set_rules('password', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_password_label'), 'required|min_length[' . $this->config->item('min_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|max_length[' . $this->config->item('max_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|matches[password_confirm]');
$this->register_form->set_rules('password_confirm', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_password_confirm_label'), 'required');
```

Registration:

```
if($this->register_form->run() == true){
    $username = strtolower($this->input->post('first_name')) . ' ' . strtolower($this->input->post('last_name'));
    $email    = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $additional_data = array(
        'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
        'last_name'  => $this->input->post('last_name'),
        'company'    => $this->input->post('company'),
        'phone'      => $this->input->post('phone'),
    );

    if($this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data)){
        $this->ion_auth->set_message_delimiters('','');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('register_message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
        redirect('home/index', 'refresh');
    }else{
        $this->ion_auth->set_error_delimiters('','');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('register_error', $this->ion_auth->errors());
        redirect('home/index', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

This is how I'm passing the flash data to my view:

```
$this->data['register_message'] = $this->session->flashdata('register_message');
$this->data['register_error'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('register_error');
```

When echoing `$register_error` with in my view, I'm not getting anything and when printing the session object with `print_r($this->session->all_userdata());` after running `register();`, the `user_data` array is empty.  I'm running `register();` with empty fields, so there should be errors.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you setting `$this->data['register_message']` ? Is there an else part to your `if($this->register_form->run() == true){` or code below the if()?

Comment: Yes, I'm setting `$this->data['register_message']` in an `if` statement below `if($this->register_form->run() == true){`.  That's not the problem, I found that `if($this->register_form->run() == true){` isn't running on form submit.

Comment: How do you mean doesn't run? If you have validation errors then it wouldn't run, because it would return false. I would suggest posting your entire register() method.

Answer (score 0):

> CodeIgniter "flashdata",will only be available for the next server
>   request, and are then automatically cleared.

Thats why you couldn't find it in session data. 
 You can preserve  flashdata variable through an additional keep_flashdata request.

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('item');
```

There is a closing brackets error in this line.

```
$this->data['register_error'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('register_error');
```

Change it to

```
$this->data['register_error'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('register_error'));
```